# Computer Assisted proofs apart from the 4 color theorem

Tags: big-list, computer-assisted-proofs

I recently read about the 4 color theorem and that it was proved using help from computers. Does anybody know of some other 'good' computer-assisted proofs apart from the 4 color theorem?

Comment: -1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_proof

Comment: You might be interested in the book *A=B* by Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger. [It is available online for free](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html).

Comment: @5PM: I can wiki 90% of the big-list on this site. But the answers here usually have personal opinions, which I can't find on wiki. Wiki doesn't tell me which is the best way to start a subject, or how highly people think of a paper. That is why I have asked it here.

Comment: There is a recent paper that you need at least 17 clues in Sudoku to ensure a unique solution. It was done through brute force computation, for 5 billion cases.

Comment: @CalvinLin: can you give the name or reference of the paper you are talking about?

Comment: For the Sudoku computer proof, see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0749).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguably second most famous computer proof in Mathematics is the one by Clement Lam showing that there is no projective plane of order 10. The computer part was a huge case-by-case analysis disproving the existence of a certain self-orthogonal code.

Comment: Thanks. got a really well documented proof.

Answer (score 4):

The proof of [Kepler's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture) by Tom Hales.

It is interesting because the initial informal mathematical proof with the help of some computer programs was considered "99% correct" by some journal reviewers after a few years of banging their head with it, which then motivated Hales to start a project to get it all computer-verified: proper formal machine-checked proofs.  See the [Flyspeck Project](http://code.google.com/p/flyspeck/)

Answer (score 2):

The proof of [The Robbins Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_algebra). I find this interesting because the proof was not the computer checking thousands of cases, it was the computer coming up with a relatively simple algebraic proof. My understanding is that the problem was so removed from human intuition and so syntactic in nature that a computer was better able to find a solution just by cleverly searching the space of proofs.

You can see a version of the proof [here](http://math.colgate.edu/~amann/MA/robbins_complete.pdf) written up by Allen Mann.